# Need help to write shell script to check if file exist or not?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script which will tell if the file or directory exist or not. It will take the input " file name " from the user.
First this will put the `ls -l` or `ls` output to a file and then take input from user (for filename), later will use if condition to check if file exist or not. But my code is not working.

```
# !/bin/bash
ls  > listtst.txt 
read -p "type file name" a
if [ listtst.txt  ==  $a  ];
  then
     echo "file is present $a"
  else
    echo "file not present"
fi
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the file listtxt.txt in your example? BTW, your sheebang-line has a bang, but no shee, and the assignment to `b` is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out,  I missed it while writing the code here. corrected it now

Comment: You did, but you messed up the formatting of the remaining code ;-)

Comment: Yea. I am using stackoverflow for the first time. still learning ..will try to edit it again :p

Comment: Your `if` condition checks uses `==`, which is not allowed in [ ... ] (see `man test` for the correct syntax). You could use `[[ == ]]`, if you need matching against a glob pattern, or `[ ... ]` for equality testing. The latter would just test, whether the user had entered the string _listtst.txt_, which is pointless: It is **obvious** that listtst.txt exists, because you have created this file just before....

Comment: Thank you :) .. I checked man test

Answer (score 2):

To check if file exist or not you can use:

```
FILE=/var/scripts/file.txt
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$FILE exist"
else 
    echo "$FILE does not exist"
fi
```

Replace "/var/scripts/file.txt" with your file path

in case you need the file path to be a variable

you can replace the file path with $1

so your code will be:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "$1 exist"
else 
    echo "$1 does not exist"
fi
```

and you have to call your script in this way:

```
./scriptname.sh "filepath"
```

Comment: You might also use `[[ -f $FILE ]]` instead.

Comment: Both will check whether $FILE exists and is a plain file. For the OPs requirements, `-e` is a more appropriate test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this code we are explicitly mentioning the file name in first line (/var/scripts/file.txt) , I want user to give the file name as input.

Comment: check the update please @Harshita

Comment: @Harshita : Then just use  the variable which you have in your code! In your code, the file is stored in a variable called `a`, so **of course** you just test with `if [[ -e $a ]]`, whether such a directory entry exists!!

Comment: Except you should quote it, like `if [ -e "$a" ]`

Comment: @tripleee : If the OP uses `[[` instead of `[`, as I advised, quoting is not necessary.